# Java Method: Integer contains 1

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method that will return true if the inputted integer has a one in it, and false if it does not.  The method works correctly when the inputted number doesn't have a one or ends in a one.  But if the one is not the last digit in the int, it incorrectly returns false.  Any ideas whats wrong?  Here is my script:

```
public static boolean hasOne(int n) {
    boolean retval = false;

    if (n % 10 == 1) {
        retval = true;
    } else {
        dropLastDig(n);
    }
    return retval;
}

public static void dropLastDig(int input) {
    int newNum = input/10;

    if (newNum > 0) {
        hasOne(newNum);
    }
}
```

1000 should return true

211 should return true

1 should return true

3 should return false

234 should return false

Comment: What do you mean by `has a one`? Does `1000` count?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Hint: if you execute the else part of `hasOne` the return value will be always `false`

Comment: Why does that happen?

Comment: Because you reach the `return retval` and the value of `retval` is still `false`. Note that a recursive invocation of `hasOne` will have an independent instance of `retval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursive function, it's faster:

```
public static boolean hasOne(int n) {
  if(n<0) return hasOne(-n); // check for negatives
  if(n==0) return false; // exit condition

  if (n % 10 == 1) {
    return true;
  } 
  return hasOne(n/10);
}
```

Or cast it to String, and then check:

```
String.valueOf(n).contains("1");
```

Comment: I think it should check for negatives

Comment: True, added a fix.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `String.valueOf` instead

```
return String.valueOf(x).contains("1");
```

Answer (score 1):

try `String.valueOf(n).contains("1")`